# WYSIWYG buttons don't show in IE for CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, liferay, fckeditor

I have a fresh installation of Liferay on Tomcat and in IE7 it doesn't show the buttons for visual editing in the editor when I try to edit content. 
It works on in Firefox or Chrome.

Does anyone have an idea why would that happen? I am not sure where to dig, I don't see javascript exceptions and it doesn't look like the buttons are even populated in IE. It is hard to debug IE problems since I don't have a tool like Firebug there.

I downloaded the 6.1 and still have the same problem, adding the URLs of what I see. Looks like IE only has the text box and in the DOM I don't see the same things that I see in FF.

http://i44.tinypic.com/35jf5td.jpg

http://i43.tinypic.com/11qqvt0.jpg

Update on this:
I checked with some people in our organization and they have the buttons on their browser. 
I checked the version of the IE browser and it's the same down to the last digit. Properties are the same as well. The only difference is that I have some plugins installed that the other browser doesn't. I tried disabling all the plugins but it didn't help.

The suspect plugin is Google Chrome Frame (ChromeFrame BHO). Can someone please try to add this plugin and see if it messes things up? The disabling it doesn't help.

Comment: If you upgrade to IE8 or IE9 (if possible), you'll get some debugging tools that might provide some hint about your problem

Comment: Not possible, unfortunately, it's a corporate standard and we need to support IE7 and test under it.

Comment: And that also means that you can't install IE8 *anywhere*?

Comment: Which version of Liferay are using 6.1 CE? I've just tried with under IE7 and I'm not getting the issue. It might be worth searching and / or posting on the Liferay forums.

Comment: I posted there, no answer: http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11251512  I use 6.0.5, I tried the tomcat bundle and have the same results. I actually tried to change the editor in the properties file, fckeditor gives javascript exception, others don't show up. And they all show up in Firefox/Chrome.

Comment: I added the pictures of what I see on fresh install of 6.1 in IE7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out, so if someone has the same problem, here is the reason - we have Google Chrome Frame plugin installed in our organization, but it only works on white-listed domain names. In this case the domain the site was on wasn't whitelisted, but the portal looked at the agent string and saw chromeframe there and assumed it can use it as chrome browser, which broke things.
Right now I will try to white-list the domain and see if it works. Another solution would be to try and find a place where we look for the agent string and fix it there, not sure where this place is.

Answer (score 1):

Liferay CE 6.0 contains few bugs within the WYSIWYG editor integration.

One issue with IE is [LPS-16004](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-16004) (solution included). This might be the same problem as you are experiencing.

I remember we had also problem with javascript race condition in editor initialization, which sometimes loads the editor incorrectly.

But I strongly suggest you to move to Liferay CE 6.1 as it is much more stable.

Comment: I tried adding DOCTYPE like suggested in comments, but it didn't help. I'll try to run the 6.1 version and see if it solves the issue I have, thanks for the tip!

Comment: If you don't have to solve complex data migration, than I am pretty confident upgrading to 6.1 will be your solution :).

Comment: Actually I just downloaded the 6.1 and made fresh install and still don't see the editor buttons in IE7. I was just thinking if there could be something else in my configuration that could affect the rendering of the buttons.

Comment: I've just tested with IETester's IE7 and everything works fine :(. Seeing only TEXTAREA probably mean there was a javascript error during the editor initialization.

Comment: Just want to let you know that I've tested with old IE7 (it was not updated) and the whole site is not working correctly. So I can confirm that IE7 has bigger problems than just the editor.

Comment: For me Liferay works ok, just the visual editor part is not working. The weirdest thing is that it worked before, but stopped at some point and I can't figure out why, may be it was some update to the IE7 in our corporation.